# I have an error with my Material UI react-swipeable-views in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, version-control, react-swipeable-views

It looks like a version of these two is not matched.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import MobileStepper from "@mui/material/MobileStepper";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import KeyboardArrowLeft from "@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowLeft";
import KeyboardArrowRight from "@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowRight";
import SwipeableViews from "react-swipeable-views";
import { autoPlay } from "react-swipeable-views-utils";

const AutoPlaySwipeableViews = autoPlay(SwipeableViews);

const images = [
  {
    label: "San Francisco – Oakland Bay Bridge, United States",
    imgPath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537944434965-cf4679d1a598?auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=250&q=60",
  },
  {
    label: "Bird",
    imgPath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538032746644-0212e812a9e7?auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=250&q=60",
  },
  {
    label: "Bali, Indonesia",
    imgPath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537996194471-e657df975ab4?auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=250",
  },
  {
    label: "Goč, Serbia",
    imgPath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512341689857-198e7e2f3ca8?auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&h=250&q=60",
  },
];

export default function Hero() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
  const maxSteps = images.length;

  const handleNext = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep - 1);
  };

  const handleStepChange = (step: number) => {
    setActiveStep(step);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ maxWidth: 400, flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <Paper
        square
        elevation={0}
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          alignItems: "center",
          height: 50,
          pl: 2,
          bgcolor: "background.default",
        }}
      >
        <Typography>{images[activeStep].label}</Typography>
      </Paper>
      <AutoPlaySwipeableViews
        axis={theme.direction === "rtl" ? "x-reverse" : "x"}
        index={activeStep}
        onChangeIndex={handleStepChange}
        enableMouseEvents
      >
        {images.map((step, index) => (
          <div key={step.label}>
            {Math.abs(activeStep - index) <= 2 ? (
              <Box
                component="img"
                sx={{
                  height: 255,
                  display: "block",
                  maxWidth: 400,
                  overflow: "hidden",
                  width: "100%",
                }}
                src={step.imgPath}
                alt={step.label}
              />
            ) : null}
          </div>
        ))}
      </AutoPlaySwipeableViews>
      <MobileStepper
        steps={maxSteps}
        position="static"
        activeStep={activeStep}
        nextButton={
          <Button
            size="small"
            onClick={handleNext}
            disabled={activeStep === maxSteps - 1}
          >
            Next
            {theme.direction === "rtl" ? (
              <KeyboardArrowLeft />
            ) : (
              <KeyboardArrowRight />
            )}
          </Button>
        }
        backButton={
          <Button size="small" onClick={handleBack} disabled={activeStep === 0}>
            {theme.direction === "rtl" ? (
              <KeyboardArrowRight />
            ) : (
              <KeyboardArrowLeft />
            )}
            Back
          </Button>
        }
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

This is my components I want to implement in App.tsx but it doesn't work. I got this error when I try that:

[image]

```
{
  "name": "my-typescript-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.11",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^6.0.0-alpha.17",
    "@types/react-swipeable-views": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/react-swipeable-views-utils": "^0.14.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.2",
    "react-swipeable-views-react-18-fix": "^0.14.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.0.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.18",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.35",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

This is my package.json. I tried to change a lot of versions but it still doesn't work.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

You only installed the type definitions for the `react-swipeable-views` package. You need to install the package itself.

Add this to your package.json `dependencies` :

```
"react-swipeable-views":"~0.14.0",
```

And Also I suggest to move the type definitions to your `devDependencies`:

```
"@types/react-swipeable-views": "^0.14.0",
"@types/react-swipeable-views-utils": "^0.14.0",
```

Comment: I tried this and its still the same issue. Tell me, if you maybe have another solution